Mathematical formulation of isotiming several vehicles routing problems
The framework of my question is the multiobjective shortest path problem over a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ whose objective vector is the following :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\sum_{ij} \vec{b}_{ij} x_{ij}
\end{equation}
where $(i)\in V$, $(j)\in V$ and $(ij)\in E$. The vector $\vec{b}_{ij}$ is
a collection of independent costs on edge $(ij)$. Variable $x_{ij}$ is binary, equals to $1$ if vehicle follows edge $(ij)$, $0$ otherwise.
The path constraint on each vertex $(i)$ usually reads as :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\sum_{j\,/\,(i,j)\in E}x_{ij} - \sum_{j\,/\,(j,i)\in E}x_{ji} =
\begin{cases}
  1 &,\,\text{if}\; i=s  \\
  -1 &,\,\text{if}\; i=t \\
  0 &,\,\text{if}\; i\notin \{s,t\}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Minimizing (1) comes to find a set of non-dominated paths : the Pareto Front.
My question is how to extend this formulation to the case of several vehicules, labeled from $1$ to $n$, so that :

each may start at a different vertices $s_1,\dots, s_n$
but all arrives at the same vertex $t$,
they take distinct paths, or at least vehicles will not meet at a given vertex (they can go through the same vertex provided it is not in the same time)
they arrive on vertex $t$ within the shortest time interval possible (isotiming)

To do so, I begin to duplicate variable $x_{ij}$ for each vehicle : $x_{ij}^{1},\dots, x_{ij}^k\dots x_{ij}^n$.
I create a supervertex $s$ linked to vertices $s_1$ to $s_n$, with $\vec{b}_{s s_k}=\vec{0}$, so that minimization (1) and path constraints (2) remain unmodified :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\forall k\;,\quad\sum_{ij} \vec{b}_{ij} x_{ij}^k
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\forall k\;,\quad\sum_{j\,/\,(i,j)\in E}x_{ij}^k - \sum_{j\,/\,(j,i)\in E}x_{ji}^k =
\begin{cases}
  1 &,\,\text{if}\; i=s  \\
  -1 &,\,\text{if}\; i=t \\
  0 &,\,\text{if}\; i\notin \{s,t\}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
but are just duplicated.
Until now, there are no coupling between vehicles, so that one could solve (1) and (2) for just one vehicle and then attribute paths of the Pareto front to each vehicles from $1$ to $n$ in a way that it makes paths sufficiently distinct and it ensures isotiming.
However, there may be not enough paths in the Pareto front and there are neither certainty that they will be sufficiently distinct nor that isotiming will be ensured.
I want to find a mathematical formulation that ensures both.
That is to say I will need to add some coupling terms between $x_{ij}^k$ variables.
First, I define $t_{ij}$ the time for a vehicle to go from vertex $(i)$ to $(j)$, assuming all vehicles have roughly identical performances.
The time travel for vehicle $k$ is :
\begin{equation}
t_k = \sum_{ij} t_{ij} x_{ij}^k
\end{equation}
Second, I define the average time travel over all vehicles :
\begin{equation}
t_m = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n t_k
\end{equation}
Finally, I modify the vector cost $\vec{b}_{ij}$ for vehicle $k$ as follows :
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\vec{b}_{ij}^k = \vec{b}_{ij}+ \vec{I}\biggl[\biggl(\sum_{uv}x_{uv}^k\biggr) t_{ij}-t_m\biggr]
\end{equation}
This means that the costs of edge $(ij)$ will increase if the time travel $t_{ij}$ is greater than the average time travel $t_m / \sum_{uv}x_{uv}$ per edge necessary to get isotiming, and conversely.
To ensure, I also increase costs of edge $(ij)$ for vehicle $k$ if other vehicles are following it.
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
\vec{b}_{ij}^k = \vec{b}_{ij}+\vec{I}\biggl(\sum_{l\ne k} c_{kl} x_{ij}^l\biggr) 
\end{equation}
where the bigger $c_{kl}$ the less vehicles $(k)$ and $(l)$ will follow same edges. This does not ensure vehicles will not meet at one vertex somehow.
Both Eqs. (5) and (6) brings quadratic term, which is what I wanted.
Do you think there are better ways to formulate this problem ?

I answer to my own question but first I would like to make it simpler.
Let's start again with the mono-objective shortest path problem for one vehicle on a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with one starting node $s$ and one terminal node $t$ :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\min_{\{x_{ij}\}}\sum_{ij} b_{ij} x_{ij}
\end{equation}
with the path constraints :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\sum_{j\,/\,(i,j)\in E}x_{ij} - \sum_{j\,/\,(j,i)\in E}x_{ji} =
\begin{cases}
  1 &,\,\text{if}\; i=s  \\
  -1 &,\,\text{if}\; i=t \\
  0 &,\,\text{if}\; i\notin \{s,t\}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Let $\{x_{ij}^{k}\}_{(i,j)\in E}$ the variables for vehicle $k$. Dealing with several vehicles, $1$ to $n$, just comes to duplicate Eqs. (1) and (2) for each vehicle $k=1,\dots,n$.
Ensuring that paths for each vehicle will be distinct comes to create the additional cost function :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\sum_{(i,j)\in E}\sum_{k\ne l} c_{kl}x_{ij}^k x_{ij}^l
\end{equation}
If both vehicles $k$ and $l$ share the same edge $(i,j)$ this cost function, that we want to minimize, will increase.
Note that at this stage, one can make a simpler version of the multi-vehicle shortest path by keeping variables $x_{ij}$ but allowing them to take values within ${0,1,\dots,n}$. Then $x_{ij}$ stands for the number of vehicles going through edge $(i,j)$.
In this case, Eq. (1) remains unchanged :
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
\min_{\{x_{ij}\}}\sum_{ij} b_{ij} x_{ij}
\end{equation}
but path conditions now read :
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\sum_{j\,/\,(i,j)\in E}x_{ij} - \sum_{j\,/\,(j,i)\in E}x_{ji} =
\begin{cases}
  n &,\,\text{if}\; i=s  \\
  -n &,\,\text{if}\; i=t \\
  0 &,\,\text{if}\; i\notin \{s,t\}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The distinct path objective function becomes :
\begin{equation}
\sum_{(i,j)\in E}x_{ij}(x_{ij} - 1)
\end{equation}
which creates and aditional cost whenever the number of vehicles going through edge $(i,j)$ is greater than 1  ($x_{ij}> 1$).
The second objective is isotiming. If I let $t_{ij}$ be the time for a vehicle to cross edge $(i,j)$, the travel time for vehicle $k$ is :
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
t_k = \sum_{ij} t_{ij} x_{ij}^k
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, I do not know how to define such a travel time with variables $x_{ij}\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$.
Ensuring isotiming then just comes to minimize :
\begin{equation}\tag{7}
\sum_k (t_k)^2 - \biggl(\sum_k t_k\biggr)^2
\end{equation}
which is nothing more than the variance of the travel times $(t_1,\dots, t_n)$.
Finally, my problem could be written as a multiobjective shortest path problem :
\begin{equation}\tag{8}
\begin{split}
&\min_{\{x_{ik}^k\}}\sum_{(ij)\in E} b_{ij} (x_{ij}^1 + \dots + x_{ij}^n)\\
&\min_{\{x_{ik}^k\}}\sum_{(i,j)\in E}\sum_{k\ne l} c_{kl}x_{ij}^k x_{ij}^l\\
&\min_{\{x_{ik}^k\}}\sum_k (t_k)^2 - \biggl(\sum_k t_k\biggr)^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
together with path constraints (2) for each vehicle.
First objective function is linear with respect to vehicles, which could be optimized independently for each vehicle, but second and third objective functions brings quadratic terms which couples vehicles between themselves.
